How can i search-query the entry attributes (slug, uri, title), if the keyword is within a matrix in a matrix?
I have entries of section "pages", which contain a matrix field. Within that matrix field, which i use a content-builder with several components, i have a component/entryType, which contains a matrix field. Those Matrix blocks have textfields, which are searchable.
When i now query graphql, it finds those matrix block, but i cannot find any property, which would let me know from which original "page" this search result is.
How can i know, which is the owner of the block and which entry is the owner of that block...?
It does not really matter, how deep you go with nested matrix blocks, as i already cannot find any information about the owner of the first level of matrix blocks. All i can query is the owner id.
Let's say, i query for the ownerId of the initial search result:
My text is here:
--> Entry (homepage) -> Matrix-Field (collapsables) -> Matrix-block (collapsable) -> Text-Field
Query 1: My query is for all entries (search: keyword)
--> I get now only the attributes from the matrix block, but besides the owner id, no information, on which section-Entry this block is.
Query 2: Query all entries with my found OwnerId
--> Now i get my Section-Entry
But if you nest it within another matrix, i have to make one query for each "level" of nesting (which is quite annoying and redundant)
There must be an easier way to get the section-Entries attributes, than making a query for each entry by its ownerId until you get to the "bottom" entry.
